# Sequelize order by two nested associations

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, sequelize.js

I try to use the `order` for both my sub-queries. But sequelize generate a bad query and use this `order by` on main-query.
Here is my query:

```
Model.findAll({
order: sequelize.literal('("asset->forOrder"."value" - "asset.currenthours") desc),
offset: 0,
limit: 10,
include: [{
  model: Asset,
  as: 'asset',
  include: [{
    model: ThresholdService,
    required: false,
    as: 'thresholdservices'
  }, {
    model: ThresholdService,
    where: {property: 'hours'},
    required: false,
    duplicating: false,
    as: 'forOrder'
  }],
}]
})
```

I expected to get query like this:

```
SELECT ..., "asset->forOrder"."asset_id", "asset->forOrder"."value"
                 FROM (
                        SELECT ...
                        FROM "machineidentity" AS "machineidentity" 
                        LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
                      ) AS "machineidentity"
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN "asset" AS "asset" ON "machineidentity"."unique_id" = "asset"."machineIdentityId"
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN "thresholdservice" AS "asset->thresholdservices" ON "asset"."id" = "asset->thresholdservices"."asset_id"
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN "thresholdservice" AS "asset->forOrder" ON "asset"."id" = "asset->forOrder"."asset_id" AND "asset->forOrder"."property" = 'hours' 
ORDER BY ("asset->forOrder"."value" - "asset"."currenthours") DESC;
```

but have:

```
SELECT ..., "asset->forOrder"."asset_id", "asset->forOrder"."value"
                 FROM (
                        SELECT ...
                        FROM "machineidentity" AS "machineidentity"
                        ORDER BY ("asset->forOrder"."value" - "asset"."currenthours") DESC
                        LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
                      ) AS "machineidentity"
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN "asset" AS "asset" ON "machineidentity"."unique_id" = "asset"."machineIdentityId"
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN "thresholdservice" AS "asset->thresholdservices" ON "asset"."id" = "asset->thresholdservices"."asset_id"
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN "thresholdservice" AS "asset->forOrder" ON "asset"."id" = "asset->forOrder"."asset_id" AND "asset->forOrder"."property" = 'hours'
ORDER BY ("asset->forOrder"."value" - "asset"."currenthours") DESC;
```

`ORDER BY` appear in `machineidentity` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in `sequelize` such code:

```
if (
      subQuery
      && Array.isArray(order)
      && order[0]
      && !(order[0] instanceof Association)
      && !(typeof order[0] === 'function' && order[0].prototype instanceof Model)
      && !(typeof order[0].model === 'function' && order[0].model.prototype instanceof Model)
      && !(typeof order[0] === 'string' && model && model.associations !== undefined && model.associations[order[0]])
    ) {
      subQueryOrder.push(this.quote(order, model, '->'));
    }
    mainQueryOrder.push(this.quote(order, model, '->'));
```

I have just created `order`, which not satisfied this `if`.
So, right now my `order`, looks like:

```
[['asset.forOrder', 'value', sequelize.literal('-(machine.asset.currentkilometers - machine.asset.initialvalueinkm)')]]
```